# Can't compile shared library under Windows due to undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

I'm using the same `waf` script, both for `Linux` and for `Windows`, to compile a `shared-library` for a program (which is able to load shared libraries at run-time).

To create this library I import some headers of the main program, so I can call main program's function in the library, and symbols are resolved at run-time, and this works under Linux.

Under Windows I'm not able to build the library because it says `undefined reference` for every function of the main program I call in the library.

What's the difference between `Windows` and `Linux` in that case? Why do I have to resolve symbols at linking-time under `Windows`? Is there a flag or something like that to avoid this?

Comment: A better question is why you don't have to do this on Linux... It doesn't make sense that the linker should just let you use undefined symbols and not care.

Comment: Do you want to create a static or dynamic library? I don't understand the structure of your modules, do you want to create a library based on the functions of your program? I suppose your program is an ".exe" how you intend to link them with the functions of the program (.exe)? Generally, it is the ".exe" which loads libraries, which in turn can load other libraries ... whereas here, from what I understand, you want to build a library with functions of your ".EXE"

Comment: Please show a [example].

Comment: I've asked another question in which I simplify the problem and show a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60380196/create-shared-library-with-undefined-reference-using-gcc-unix-windows-differenc)

Answer (score 1):

Linux allows unresolved symbols in a shared library, but Windows does not.
I have no good knowledge of the reasons of this difference. In https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libtool/2007-04/msg00070.html for example you can see one opinion that on Linux it is "to allow circular references in shared libraries".

On Windows you can get the same behavior as on Linux with the `/FORCE:UNRESOLVED` linker parameter (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/force-force-file-output?view=msvc-170), but it has a restriction, namely your DLL must have an entry point.

On Linux you can get the same behavior as on Windows with `-Wl,-no-undefined` linker parameter. Additionally you can use a parameter `-Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined` to disallow undefined symbols only in shared libraries which you link against (see https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).